# How can I properly create a class that contains a union composed of an instance of a different class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, oop, object

I am trying to create an array of class instances to represent a physical environment. Each AreaUnit class instance has a union that can hold one of two different classes which represent two differ:ent environment characteristics(in this case the presence of a node, which has physical significance for my project.

I am trying to compile in Visual Studios, and when I do I get the following error: "E1790   the default constructor of "AreaUnit::location" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function" in the AreaUnit.cpp file. What's going on? why would a union require a default constructor and why wouldn't the compiler provide one?

Code:

AreaUnit.h:

```
    #pragma once
    #include "Area.h"
    #include "Node.h"

    class AreaUnit
    {
    private:
        bool    node;        
        union location
        {
            Node    N;
            Area    A;
        } loc;
    public:
        AreaUnit();
        AreaUnit(bool);

        bool getBool();
        void setBool(bool);
        Node getNode();
        Area getArea();


        ~AreaUnit();
    };
```

AreaUnit.cpp:

```
    #include "Area.h"
    #include "Node.h"
    #include "AreaUnit.h"

    AreaUnit::AreaUnit() { ; }
    AreaUnit::AreaUnit(bool bb) { node = bb; if (node) loc.N = Node();                 else loc.A = Area(); }

    bool AreaUnit::getBool()
    {
        return (this->node);
    }
    void AreaUnit::setBool(bool _node)
    {
        this->node = _node;
    }
    Node AreaUnit::getNode()
    {
        return (this->loc.N);
    }

    Area AreaUnit::getArea()
    {
        return (this->loc.A);
    }

    AreaUnit::~AreaUnit() { ; }
```

Main.cpp (it's stripped down for clarity, if needed I'll provide more: it's trying to initialize of array of AreaUnit instances)

```
    using namespace std;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////GLOBAL_VARIABLE_AND_FUNCTION_DECLARATIONS/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    AreaUnit env[10][10]; 

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////BODY_OF_PROGRAM///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    int main()
    {return 0;}
```

Comment: The definitions of the `Area` and `Node` classes are important here.  Please add them to the question.

Comment: From cppreference: If a union contains a non-static data member with a non-trivial special member function (copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment, or destructor), that function is deleted by default in the union and needs to be defined explicitly by the programmer.

Comment: Possible X/Y problem?

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem appears to be that either `Node` or `Area` (or both of them) has a non trivial constructor. A trivial constructor is a constructor that literally does nothing - it does not initialize any member and does not perform any other actions.

Consider the following example:

```
union SomeUnion {
    std::vector<int> v1;
    std::vector<int> v2;
};
```

What should happen in this case? Should `v1` be constructed, or `v2`? Similarly, what should happen in union's destructor? Both members share the same storage, so if both destructors are called we end up with a double free and a crash.

To avoid such situation, there is a restriction that a union has a default constructor generated by a compiler only when all members are have trivial constructors and a destructor generated by a compiler when all members have trivial destructors. In such case, there is no problem, as trivial constructors and destructors do nothing.

In your case, it is necessary to define a constructor (and maybe a destructor) for the union, so that you can call appropriate constructors and destructors yourself.

The following example shows how to do this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int v;

    A()
        : v(0)
    {
        std::cout << "A()\n";
    }

    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "~A()\n";
    }
};

struct B
{
    int v;

    B()
        : v(1)
    {
        std::cout << "B()\n";
    }

    ~B()
    {
        std::cout << "~B()\n";
    }
};

union AB
{
    A a;
    B b;

    AB()
        : a()
    {}

    ~AB()
    {
        a.~A();
    }
};

int main()
{
    AB ab;
    return 0;
};
```

The expected output is:

```
A()
~A()
```